# What are these bitwise operations doing

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

```
uint sum = generateSum();
int forced = getForcedBitfield();
int previousSum = getPreviousSum();

sum = (~forced & sum) + (forced & previousSum);
```

What exactly is the last line doing? The sum is 32 boolean values. It is a bitfield. Forced is a bitfield and previousSum is a bitfield.

In plain English what is the last line doing? (Not the operations, I know it nots forced and ands it with sum then adds this to forced anded with previous sum)

Comment: Impossible to tell until  more context is provided.

Comment: It takes all the bits from `sum` which are not forced (i.e. `~forced` has a 1 there) and adds that sum to the `previousSum`, whereby `forced` selects the bits from `previousSum` prior to addition.

Comment: I am trying to turn those bitfields into arrays and I need to change the bitwise logic into regular logic...

Comment: Just write out some values in binary and do the math. `~` = bitwise not, `&` = bitwise and, etc...

Comment: This looks like someone wanted to avoid writing IF statements, and instead has you scratching your head.  Suggest you find who wrote this (use blame tool in your version control) and ask them.

Comment: @WarrenP: IF statements would reasonably replace logical operations (`&&`, `||`), but would be totally ineffective for working bitwise.

Comment: This looks like some kind of saturating-adder. But I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will selectively pick bits from both values (`sum` & `previousSum`), where "on" bits come from `previousSum` and "off" bits come from `sum`.

Because the two operands of the addition operation have mutually exclusive bits set to 1, an addition had the same effect as Boolean Or in this case.

It's like using a stencil to combine two images.

To see how this works, let's use 4 bit values:

> forced = 0011 (and ~forced = 1100)
>   previousSum = 0110
>   sum = 1111
>   ~forced & sum = 1100
>   forced & previousSum = 0010

No bits are "on" in both values, so summation is same as OR, and the effect is equal to choosing bits from both valid to construct a new value.

Comment: Maybe you could point out in the answer that the `+` is the same as `|` in this case because `forced & x` and `~forced & x` mean that there can't be any carries? That might be the source of confusion for the asker.

Comment: So for each bit in sum... if sum[x] is not forced, then use previousSum[x] else use sum[x] ?

Comment: If forced then previousSum, Sum otherwise.